# Java Maven HyperSQL

Tags: java, hsqldb, tomcat8

How to query HyperSQL using jdbc:hsqldb URL?

For example, consider this [sample source code](https://github.com/ipower634/rest-api-sample-app-java)

The HSQL Database Manager using the following command does not work.

```
java -cp "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\rest-api-sample-app-java-1.0\WEB-INF\lib\hsqldb-2.2.9-jdk5.jar" org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManager
```

How to go about querying the HyperSQL embedded database with jar files?

Please refer to the following screenshots.

[image]

[image]

What is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: First thing that stands-out is you only have one JAR file in your command line classpath.  Is this the correct way?  Not `java -jar ...`?

Comment: What is `ppusers`? Have you created this database object (f.e. table) before?

Comment: https://github.com/ipower634/rest-api-sample-app-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/paypal/dao/DBConnection.java

con.createStatement().executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE ppusers (userid INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1) not null,email VARCHAR(20),password VARCHAR(200),creditcard_id VARCHAR(40))");

Comment: I think you should remove the word Maven from the title of your question.  This isn't a question about Maven.

Answer (score 0):

The jdbc URL you are using begins with **jdbc:hsqldb:mem:**.  This means you are accessing a 100% in-memory database.

It looks like the jdbc URL you are trying to access should start with **jdbc:hsqldb:file:**.  It is referenced in [DBConnection.java](https://github.com/ipower634/rest-api-sample-app-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/paypal/dao/DBConnection.java) as:

```
jdbc:hsqldb:file:" + dbPath + ";user=SA;create=true"
```

The dbPath will be whatever *System.getProperty("user.home")* returns with  *\testpaymentdb* appended on the end of it.

Please also see HyperSQL's documentation about [In-Process (Standalone) Mode](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch01.html#N101A8) which talks about how you cannot access the database file at the same time as the web application is running.